# AWS EC2 Http Requests Timeout and Website Cannot Be Accessed

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, http

I have a web application at https://cubicl.io/

It is hosted on AWS EC2 instance. It works without problem but sometimes website cannot be accessed. When I look at the Chrome developer console I see that requests are pending or timed out:

[Network activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKebp.png)

I checked the EC2 instance. CPU usage is around 5%. Half of the RAM is used. And hard drive has lots of free space. This happens for 30-60 minutes randomly. Then, web site continues to work without problem. It responds very fast.

When this problem occurs I can ping the server, access it with SSH and download files over SSH and connection is very fast but somehow HTTP requests don't reach the server.

I noticed that if I connect to the website over a VPN connection it works without problem. If I close the VPN, I cannot reach it. Because of that I started to think that this might be a network or DNS problem. I use Route53.

I could't go further than this. What should I check to see the source of the problem? How can I fix a problem like this?

Comment: what instance type are you using?

Comment: @Mike It is t2.micro